# What is the difference (in terms of idea) of mode, storage.mode, typeof in R?

Tags: r, language-concepts

## My research so far

Most articles discuss the difference between `class` and `typeof` but I haven't found much to the differences between `mode`, `storage.mode`, and `typeof`.

I get that `mode`, `storage.mode`, and `typeof` are more similar and `class` is more different. I get that the former two call `typeof` and I understand that they handle specific types slightly differently (I even know which ones and how). What I would like to know is what the idea behind that is.

## Minimal working example

```
library(data.table)

my_vector_boolean <- c(TRUE, FALSE, T, F)
my_vector_integer <- c(1L, 2L, 3L)
my_vector_character <- c("a", "b", "abc")
my_vector_factor <- as.factor(c("a", "b", "c"))
my_list <- list(a=1, b=2L, c="c")
my_matrix <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
                    dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"), c("col1", "col2", "col3")))
my_dataframe <- data.frame(1, 1L:10L, sample(3, 10, replace = TRUE))
my_datatable <- data.table(1, 1L:10L, sample(3, 10, replace = TRUE))

datatypeslist <- list(
  my_vector_boolean = my_vector_boolean,
  my_vector_integer = my_vector_integer,
  my_vector_character = my_vector_character,
  my_vector_factor = my_vector_factor,
  my_list = my_list,
  my_matrix = my_matrix,
  my_dataframe = my_dataframe,
  my_datatable = my_datatable
  )

multi.sapply <- function(...) {
      arglist <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
      var.names <- sapply(arglist, deparse)
      has.name <- (names(arglist) != "")
      var.names[has.name] <- names(arglist)[has.name]
      arglist <- lapply(arglist, eval.parent, n = 2)
      x <- arglist[[1]]
      arglist[[1]] <- NULL
      result <- sapply(arglist, function (FUN, x) sapply(x, FUN), x)
      colnames(result) <- var.names[-1]
      return(result)
}

multi.sapply(datatypeslist, typeof, storage.mode, mode, class)
```

## What I am looking for

What kind of answer I am **not** looking for: "`mode` and `storage.mode` handle `single` differently.

What kind of answer I **am** loking for: "`typeof` is the data type that is used in the underlying C implementation, while `mode` is the data type that ... and `storage.mode` is the data type that ..."

Additionally I would appreciate a differentiation of the terms "mode" and "type" that have been used in manuals and tutorials. For example it has been said that `typeof` return the mode of a data object - which seems confusing to me.

---

I hope that question was specific/clear enough. Please tell me what was not clear, before down-voting or voting for closing.

Comment: Well, [Hadley says this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html): "You may have heard of `mode()` and `storage.mode()`. I recommend ignoring these functions because they’re just aliases of the names returned by `typeof()`, **and exist solely for S compatibility**." If I understand the last bit of your post correctly, this is approaching the kind of answer you want, right? Edit: Also, maybe the R documentation helps: [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/manual/R-lang.html#Objects).

Comment: @Laterow: Yes, I think that is helping a lot. The R documentation you linked too has been read by me, but hasn't answered by question. The link to Hadley is more useful. If you like you can make an answer from this.

Comment: @Laterow:  Also, maybe you can explain the difference of the terms "type" and "mode" in tutorials (see the question).

Comment: I think it's very safe to say that G. Grothendieck knows significantly more about this kind of stuff than I do. You'd probably get much better answers from him :) @Make42

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof` is the key function.

The others are variations of `typeof` that exist solely for the purpose of S compatibilty and are mostly not used today.

`storage.mode` can be used in S when call calling .Fortran or .C with numeric data so you know whether an input is an `integer` or `double`, say.  This distinction can often be blurred in R but when passing objects to these languages the distinction is important.   It is like `typeof` in this respect.  `mode` just gives `numeric` for both of these so it is coarser.

```
> mode(1L)
[1] "numeric"
> storage.mode(1L)
[1] "integer"

> mode(1)
[1] "numeric"
> storage.mode(1)
[1] "double"
```

Their operation is best understood by looking at their source.  In both cases the source is pretty short.

For example, `storage,mode` returns the same value as `typeof` unless the value returned by `typeof` is `"closure"`, `"builtin"` or `"special"` and in those cases returns `"function"`.

```
storage.mode <- function (x) 
   switch(tx <- typeof(x), closure = , builtin = , special = "function", tx)
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but that is exactly what I already wrote in my question and exactly the kind of answer I was not looking for - also - as already stated in my question.

Comment: Have clarified how they are used in S.

Comment: Can you add some words to the usage of the terms "mode" and "type" or is this just something tutorials use interchangeably without having put much thought into the exact use of the terminology?

Comment: I don't think mode really has an intended meaning in R.  It relates to S.  Just ignore it.

Comment: Might be helpful to point out the `mode<-`  and `storage.mode<-` usages, which have no analogue in `typeof`... Almost all instances of `storage.mode` I see in the R source (cloned from GitHub) are akin to `storage.mode(x) = 'double'`